# Why couldn't I select one option from this Radio button which I made using Angular 14?

Tags: angular, angular-material

```
<mat-radio-group aria-label="gender" name="gen">
         <mat-radio-button value="male">Male</mat-radio-button>
         <mat-radio-button value="Female">Female</mat-radio-button>
         <mat-radio-button value="Others">Others</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

I also tried providing a similar value for the **name attribute** to each radio button, but haven't worked in my favor.

Comment: Please explain better your problem. The radio can't be selected? you are using ngmodel directive or a formgroup  to get the values?

Comment: try adding ```[]``` on value like this ```[value]``` also can you post your typescript?

Comment: @MarcGuillem I can select the options, but my need is to let anyone select only one option at once,  I am using formgroup, but here I just want to know how to let the options work propper like the below example.
like this ->[link] (https://material.angular.io/components/radio/overview#radio-overview)

Comment: @L.K.Kabilan So do you want to know how each radio button is related with others to work properly right? Your problem is that you can select all radios at the same time?
Is weird because is very simple, if you put the radios over mat-radio-group it should be working with no problems, post your entire code please :)

Comment: You can read more about it in radio-groups section: https://material.angular.io/components/radio/overview#radio-groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the confusions above,
finally the **option type input worked fine** after importing **MatInputModule**, in the app.modules
**import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';**

so it's It is important to ensure that the MatInputModule module is imported in your Angular application, as it provides Material Design styling and functionality for your form input fields. If you neglect to include this module, you may encounter errors related to missing directives or components in your templates, which may be easily overlooked or dismissed. Therefore, it is recommended to include the MatInputModule to ensure that your input fields function as intended and to avoid any potential errors in your application.

```
<mat-card-content
  class="bg-gray-200 flex justify-center items-center min-h-screen min-w-full"
>
  <div class="main-container bg-white p-5 shadow-2xl rounded-3xl">
    <div class="p-3 flex justify-center">
      <mat-card-header Class="font-bold text-sm text-purple-700">
        Registration
      </mat-card-header>
    </div>

    <form
      action=""
      class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center content-center"
      [formGroup]="formRegister"
      (ngSubmit)="proceedRegistration()"
    >
      <mat-form-field class="w-2/3">
        <input
          matInput
          formControlName="id"
          placeholder="ID"
          type="text"
          class="rounded-lg shadow-md bg-gray-200"
        />
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field class="w-2/3">
        <input
          matInput
          formControlName="name"
          placeholder="User Name"
          type="text"
          class="rounded-lg shadow-md bg-gray-200"
        />
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-radio-group name="gender" formControlName="gender">
        <mat-radio-button id="male" value="male" name="male">Male</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button id="female" value="female">Female</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button id="others" value="others">Others</mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>

      <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="w-2/3">
        <mat-label>Role</mat-label>
        <select
          formControlName="role"
          mat-select
          matNativeControl
          class="bg-gray-200 rounded-2xl p-2"
        >
          <option value="admin" class="text-purple-700">Admin</option>
          <option value="technician" class="text-purple-700">Technician</option>
          <option value="user" class="text-purple-700">User</option>
        </select>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field class="w-2/3">
        <input
          matInput
          formControlName="email"
          placeholder="Email"
          type="email"
          class="rounded-lg shadow-md bg-gray-200"
        />
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field class="w-2/3">
        <input
          matInput
          formControlName="password"
          id="passW"
          placeholder="Password"
          type="password"
          class="rounded-lg shadow-md bg-gray-200"
        />
      </mat-form-field>

      <div>
        <button class="rounded-full p-1 bg-purple-700 text-white">
          Register
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>

    <a
      class="hover:text-purple-700 text-sm py-1 px-2 rounded"
      routerLink="/Login"
    >
      Login
    </a>
  </div>
</mat-card-content>
```

**and this is the type script**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, PatternValidator, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/service/auth/auth.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-up',
  templateUrl: './sign-up.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-up.component.css', '../../../../assets/CSS/FormDesign.css']

})

export class SignUpComponent {
  constructor(private builder: FormBuilder, private toastr: ToastrService,
    private service: AuthService, private route: Router) {

  }

  formRegister = this.builder.group({
    id: this.builder.control('', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)])),
    name: this.builder.control('', Validators.required),
    gender: this.builder.control(''),
    role: this.builder.control('', Validators.required),
    email: this.builder.control('', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])),
    password: this.builder.control('', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}$")])),
    isactive: this.builder.control(false)
  });

  proceedRegistration() {
    if (this.formRegister.valid) {
      console.log("works Fine")
      this.service.proceedRegister(this.formRegister.value).subscribe(res => { this.toastr.success("Resgistered Successfull") });
      this.route.navigate(['/Login'])
    } else {
      console.log(this.formRegister)
      this.toastr.warning("Please Enter a Valid Data!")
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an array of values and rendering it into the radio buttons through a predefined directive (*ngFor) made the radio buttons kind of unique which lets anyone select only one option among many.

```
  <mat-radio-group aria-label="gender" class="w-10/12"  name="gen">
            <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let gender of genders">{{g}}</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-group>
```

**typescript(tc)**

```
genders =['male','female','others']
```

Comment: Sorry, I can not understand you. The only problem with your before code (and with this) is that, when you add the property `name` to the mat-radio-group, all the inputs type radio that will be generated has de same name -So if you have another input with the same name you has a problem-. NOTE: If you use a formGroup , remove the "name" attribute, just simple `<mat-radio-group aria-label="gender" class="w-10/12" formControlName="nameOfYourFormControl">`